# How to set slice for reverse hex

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, slice

Need help with slice of a hex to reverse

I have

```
                b = str(valueh)
                c = str(valueh)[-1:1:-1]
                if all(x in string.hexdigits for x in c):
                    d = int(c, 16)
                    print(hex(d))
```

for example for a value os 0x123456 this prints 0x654321 and i need it to print 0x563412.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: `a = 0x123456; b = int.from_bytes(a.to_bytes(a.bit_length() // 8 + 1, "big"), "little")`

Comment: hi, thanks but this returns 5649426

Comment: ... which is decimal form of number. Try `hex(5649426)` ;-)

Comment: HAHAHA awsome :) thanks

Comment: a=int(value, base=16)

Answer (score 0):

This code allows for strings with or without 0x prefix and also strings with an odd number of characters:-

```
def rev(s):
    if not s:
        return s
    if (prefix := s[0:2] if s.lower().startswith('0x') else ''):
        sl = list(s[2:])
    else:
        sl = list(s)
    if (j := len(sl) - 2) >= 2:
        i = 0
        while True:
            sl[i:i + 2], sl[j:j + 2] = sl[j:j + 2], sl[i:i + 2]
            if (i := i + 2) >= (j := j - 2):
                break
    return prefix + ''.join(sl)


print(rev('0x123456'))
```